# Can someone help me with the purrr: map function

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function "compute_gini" with 4 inputs.

```
compute_gini(df, var, split, minsplit)
```

I want it to run let's say 200 times but each time it runs, the input value for split should get increased by 1. Is it possible to run this function multiple times with the purrr:map function?
For example...

```
compute_gini(df , var , 1 , minsplit)
compute_gini(df , var , 2 , minsplit)
compute_gini(df , var , 3 , minsplit)
compute_gini(df , var , 4 , minsplit)
compute_gini(df , var , 5 , minsplit)
.....
compute_gini(df , var , 200 , minsplit)
```

update:

I tried this function below and it worked!

```
  purrr::map(.x = 1:200, .f = compute_gini, df = penguins_sub, var = bm,  minsplit = 1)
```

Comment: What to you want for an output in return? One Gini-value for each split?

Comment: @julian yes I am trying to get Gini Value for each split.

Comment: Hi, have you tried something like: `purrr::map(.x = 1:200, .f = compute_gini, df = ***, var = ***, minsplit = ***)`? With `***` being your actual inputs for these variables.

Comment: @Marcuswas minsplit is just a constant 1.

Comment: Could you please make your example reproducible? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. We do not know what your function is neither what the objects and the expected ouput are.

Comment: @paul 
`purrr::map(.x = 1:200, .f = compute_gini, df = ***, var = ***, minsplit = ***)`
This code worked well and solved my problem!
Thankssssssss!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to `map` over the vector `1:200`  for ex. Note that you can use `seq` to make this vector in another way.

Then, this should work:

```r
fn <- function(a, b, c, d) {
  a + b + c + d
}
purrr::map(.x = 1:200, .f = fn, a = 1, c = 1, d = 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 4
...
#> [[200]]
#> [1] 203
```

This is the same output (but in a list) as:

```r
fn(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1)
#> [1] 4
fn(a = 1, b = 2, c = 1, d = 1)
#> [1] 5
fn(a = 1, b = 3, c = 1, d = 1)
#> [1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to combine the function with a for-loop: `for (i in 1:200) {compute_gini(df, var, i, minsplit)}`